# Centering bad the items from my grid and add 5 squares per row

Tags: css

What I want is for each row to show five squares, and center it in the middle of the container, so far what I have is this ..

***Code:***

```
.sala { /* div parent */
  background-color: grey;
  order:4;
 margin-top:20px;

}

.sala__aforo { /*div son , displays the squares*/
  /* Separación entre asientos */
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;  
  gap: 25px;
}
```

This is the image displaying the bad position of the items.
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irsm2.png)

Comment: Hi can you post your HTML code as well?

Comment: Some of the code(like squares) are generate in javascript like divs

Comment: Can you post the js then?

Comment: added html , and some of the cood js which is generated

Comment: in contenidoHTML is where squares are creating

Comment: Possibly try making this change in your CSS: `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;`

Comment: Yeah i tried and add 5columns which is ok , but the items arent centered in each row

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Or better yet, a working codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you need to do these things in CSS:

Remove `margin: 50px;` from `.lienzo`

remove `place-content: start start;` from `.sala__aforo`

remove  `margin-left: 13px;` from `.asiento--ocupado`

and remove `margin-left: 21px;` from `.asiento--seleccionado`

And it should work.

Comment: Yeah! It works i missed .asiento-xxx , thank you man for your time